# In JMeter, is there a way of testing an autocomplete that cancels requests

Tags: autocomplete, jmeter

I'll start this question with 'this is not the same as the previous one'. I can see straightaway that an almost identical question has been asked but the answer is not what I'm after. I will explain...

I need to test an autocomplete search box in a web page. Normally I'd just do a series of requests with the HTML containing one extra letter each time (which is the answer to the other question similar to this). Problem is, that's not how the page behaves. It does submit a new request each time I type a letter, but it's cancelling the previous one instead of letting it continue. Therefore the only one that actually gets to a HTTP 200 response is the very last one.

This blog contains an example of what I'm seeing;

[Autocomplete and request cancellation](https://www.gmarik.info/blog/2016/autocompletion-request-cancellation-jquery-and-go/)

But about halfway down it shows our test condition;

> Client cancellation must also be supported by the search backend. Backend that doesn’t support cancellation continues processing request even after client disconnects.

I need to write a jmeter script that replicates a series of cancelled requests, followed by a single successful request, such that when I look on the backend I either see multiple running queries (bad) or just the last one (good).

Edit: I've also hit a follow up issue, how to identify canceled requests in web server logs. It looks like I'm only seeing single requests if they are allowed to complete (IE if I pause between letters). If the requests are cancelled, they don't get logged in the log. So, how do I verify that they happened at all? If we import the logs into a visualization tool, are we going to be missing the 'canceled' requests.

Answer (score 0):

"Request cancellation" is nothing more than [closing the connection from the client side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort)

The easiest way of implementing it in JMeter is setting the response timeout, the setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

[image]

Just set this timeout to be lower than the threshold configured in your frontend and JMeter will close the connection making the backend "think" that the autocomplete request has been aborted because the user is still typing.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Aha, I can see what you're doing there, definitely an interesting approach and I understand where it comes from now... since the search is within a larger workflow I'll have to set the abort timeout on the request itself, the request defaults will be the normal 2 minute browser equivalent. I also need to figure out how to ensure they don't show as red in the logs, just so they don't raise any questions (managers hate red lines on reports!). Thanks for your advice (and the cool demo!).